# How to disable a submit button for a week

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to allow someone to update a field in a database once a week, i want to disable the submit button

```
var enableSubmit = function() {
    console.log(this);
    $(this).removeProp("disabled");
}

$("#test").click(function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(enableSubmit, 100000000000);
});
```

would work, obviously a bigger timer is needed but each time he refreshes the page, the timer would reset, I know ideally you would want to do that in a server side script, but security isn't an issue now, still if you prefer php, then i have no problem.

Comment: If security really isn't an issue you could use a cookie or local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the last submitted timestamp in a cookie or localStorage, have the `button` set to disabled on rendering and enable it with JavaScript if the last submitted timestamp in the cookie/localStorage has passed the 1-week mark.

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    localStorage.setItem('last_submitted_time', new Date().getTime());
});
```

And then in your `$(document).ready()` or some initializer you might have

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var lastSubmittedTime = +localStorage.getItem('last_submitted_time') || 0;
if (now - lastSubmittedTime >= 604800000) {
    // Enable the submit button.
}
```